# Navigate to previous page in c#?

Tags: c#, navigation

I was wondering if there was an easy way to navigate back to the previous page of a site using c#?

I am aware it can be done using JavaScript but I was wondering if there was an equivalent in c#

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is not guaranteed to be aware of the previous page that the browser visited.  If you really want to go this route, you can try have a look at [Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx), or get it out of `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]`.

I would advise against those though; if you really need to make a decision server side and redirect to the previous page, manually keeping track of the previous page (as part of the URL or a form variable) would be the best way to make sure this happens in a reliable fashion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a client function, and the server may not know the previous page (in certain circumstances, there might not even be a "previous page").

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer